# Disk saturated by mariadb on CentOS 7, blocks everything

Tags: performance, centos7, mariadb, io

For the past few days I have been having a problem with a webserver running CentOS 7. Every 13-14 minutes some operation (which I identified with mariadb using iostat) seems to completely saturate the disk IO operations, blocking all other applications. After about 3 minutes everything returns to normal.

In /var/log/messages I see:

```
Sep 14 09:35:42 MY-VM kernel: mptscsih: ioc0: attempting task abort! (sc=ffff9aefd1e76d80)
Sep 14 09:35:42 MY-VM kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 2a 8b 1b 18 00 00 10 00
Sep 14 09:35:42 MY-VM kernel: mptscsih: ioc0: task abort: SUCCESS (rv=2002) (sc=ffff9aefd1e76d80)
Sep 14 09:35:42 MY-VM kernel: mptscsih: ioc0: attempting task abort! (sc=ffff9aefd1e741c0)
Sep 14 09:35:42 MY-VM kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0f 37 0a 58 00 00 08 00
Sep 14 09:35:42 MY-VM kernel: mptscsih: ioc0: task abort: SUCCESS (rv=2002) (sc=ffff9aefd1e741c0)
Sep 14 09:35:42 MY-VM kernel: mptscsih: ioc0: attempting task abort! (sc=ffff9aefd1e74700)
Sep 14 09:35:42 MY-VM kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0f 37 0a 38 00 00 10 00
Sep 14 09:35:42 MY-VM kernel: mptscsih: ioc0: task abort: SUCCESS (rv=2002) (sc=ffff9aefd1e74700)
```

I've been monitoring the queries, but I can't find anything significant.

Comment: Make a backup and replace disk drive, it looks like it's going to fail soon. What filesystem do you use?

Comment: I'm using ext4 filesystem. The machine in on VMWare, I've restored it from a backup because I had problems with the original machine. It's strange that the disk drive is broken on both machines.

Comment: What kind of backup was it? Was it a full disk image kind of backup or did you use some backup software?

Comment: Also, what kind of drive do you use?

Comment: @paladin it was the backup of the full virtual machine, it's a virtual drive

Comment: If your filesystem was stored on a previous malfunctioning disk drive, it has marked badblocks, data sectors which are faulty and which should never been used again. This badblock list is still in use and results in an increased data/file fragmentation and thus decreases performance. You should "reset" this badblocks list and manually run a defragmentation of your ext4 filesystem. Make sure you have a backup before doing so.

Comment: Removing badblocks list: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18826/is-it-possible-to-reset-the-badblocks - defragmenting filesystem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/221079/how-to-defrag-an-ext4-filesystem#620966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the problem was with one of these softwares (removed with yum):

- desktop-file-utils-0.23-2.el7.x86_64
- emacs-filesystem-1:24.3-23.el7_9.1.noarch
- libsecret-0.18.6-1.el7.x86_64
- libxkbfile-1.0.9-3.el7.x86_64
- xdg-utils-1.1.0-0.17.20120809git.el7.noarch